# Are there "ordinal numbers objects"?

Tags: natural-numbers, cartesian-closed-categories

I've been reading [Hagino's thesis](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.05167) introducing CPL, and they have a gem of a definition on p123:

```
left object ord with pro is
    ozero : 1 → ord
    sup : exp(nat, ord) → ord
end object
```

To translate from CPL into something more familiar, let us work in a Cartesian closed category with a natural numbers object $\Bbb{N}$, and have $O$ be an object equipped with arrows $z : 1 \to O$ and $s : O^\Bbb{N} \to O$, such that for any $f : 1 \to X$ and $g : X^\Bbb{N} \to X$, $\exists!k : O \to X$ making the following diagram commute:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
1 @> z >> O @< s << O^\Bbb{N} \\
@| @V k VV @V k \circ - VV \\
1 @> f >> X @< g << X^\Bbb{N}
\end{CD}

Hagino calls $k$ the $\mathrm{pro}(f,g)$, which might stand for "primitive recursion on ordinals", but I'm not sure exactly what this is. Could this be a categorical definition of an ordinal numbers object?

Edit: From a discussion in `#categorytheory` on Libera IRC, we suspect that this definition cannot possibly work without one additional natural transformation in the CPL declaration:

```
osucc : ord → ord
```

This would cause Hagino's definition to line up with [Escardó's definition of ordinals in Agda](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Emhe/papers/ordinals/ordinals.html). The informal reasoning is that ordinals can be constructed by starting at zero, taking a successor ordinal, or taking a limit ordinal; this means that we need three constructors.

Comment: I don’t think this definition works. It would define a new, distinct “ordinal” for every sequence of “ordinals”, which is not how ordinals actually work.

Comment: Very strange to call these "ordinals".  The "sup" name suggests it is taking a supremum of ordinals but if you take just the free object with these operations then it won't behave anything like that.

Comment: Adding a successor operation doesn't really help.  The problem is that the sup operation on ordinals is very very far from being "free"; it satisfies lots of relations.

Comment: I agree with your analysis. I don't presume to understand Hagino or Escardó. Could there be a categorical encoding of the supremum as some sort of limit on an infinite diagram?